# Encryption, authentication and external access for Confluent Kafka on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm

Am trying to configure Encryption, authentication and external access for Confluent Kafka on Kubernetes.

helm chart https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts.

Document following : https://medium.com/weareservian/encryption-authentication-and-external-access-for-confluent-kafka-on-kubernetes-69c723a612fc

As per document I have configured

1. secrets.yaml
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bakuppus/kafka-demo/master/secrets.yaml
2. Statefulset.yaml 
   https://github.com/bakuppus/kafka-demo/blob/master/cp-helm-charts/charts/cp-kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml

While set SSL as per
export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=SSL://${POD_IP}:9092,EXTERNAL://${HOST_IP}:$((31090 + ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID})) && \

Pods are getting CrashLoopBackOff

my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka-0                            2/3     CrashLoopBackOff   3          2m40s
my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka-1                            2/3     CrashLoopBackOff   3          2m13s
my-confluent-oss-cp-kafka-2                            2/3     Error              3          111s

kubectl logs error

SSL is enabled.
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub template /etc/confluent/docker/kafka.properties.template /etc/kafka/kafka.properties] FAILED !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have plaintext passwords in the `secrets.yaml` file: they need to be base64 encoded like the keystore files.

Also, it looks like you're missing a protocol mapping for the named EXTERNAL listener, `KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP` environment variable should be:

```
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
          value: SSL:SSL,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SSL
```

Comment: Thanks much Ryan, base64 encode resolve previous error, still pods are crashing and getting below error: 

===> Configuring ...
SSL is enabled.
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.broker.keystore.jks exists] FAILED !
[root@ip-172-31-53-106 kafka]#

Comment: @Rayan

**How to resolve **

` SSL is enabled.
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /etc/kafka/secrets/kafka.broker.keystore.jks exists] FAILED ! `

Thanks

Comment: Statefulset is missing the volumeMount to mount the secrets to /etc/kafka/secrets path - check the article for example. You have it listed under the wrong container

Comment: Thanks Ryan, mount issue fixed as followed yours.

Comment: Still PODs getting crash with error

[2019-05-26 06:28:56,270] ERROR Fatal error during SupportedServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'SSL://10.60.0.28:9093,EXTERNAL://10.60.0.4:31090': No security protocol defined for listener SSL

Comment: is `KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP` set like in original answer? that error indicates theres no mapping for the SSL advertised listener

Comment: Yes Ryan, please look on https://github.com/bakuppus/kafka-demo/blob/master/cp-helm-charts/charts/cp-kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml

Comment: FYI: -  I have pushed my latest code here - 
https://github.com/bakuppus/kafka-demo